# Selecting One String from data list in Python

Tags: python, random, python-3.3

I am relatively new to programming, so be easy on me.

I have made a program (much like a magic 8 ball) that the user asks a question, and then I have created a list with all my answers inside of it (14 answers). My program shuffles all the answers, but then I now need to assign every piece of data (using a random number generator from 1-14 (which I've completed), and then have it match the shuffled data with a random number and print that.

I have created the random number generator, and the answer list shuffles.  I just need to know how to assign the number to the strings in my list, and then print that one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists have indices; if your number is between 0 and 13 (inclusive), then you can just use that directly on your list:

```
print(answers[random_number])
```

However, the `random` module has a dedicated function for just this use case; [`random.choice()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) picks one value from a sequence at random:

```
print(random.choice(answers))
```

No need to shuffle anything that way..

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> answers = ['Without a doubt!', 'Hmmm, not so sure', 'By the winds, set sail now!', 'Oh no, no NO NO!!']
>>> print(random.choice(answers))
Hmmm, not so sure
>>> print(random.choice(answers))
Oh no, no NO NO!!
```